# De-identifying storages in Google Cloud DLP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I was using a dataflow streaming template for DLP deidentification from GCS to BQ. I wanted a batch solution. I found out cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-storage, which provided a new "deidentify" action for the create_dlp_job function. When I tried to call that API, it said
"Protocol message Action has no "deidentify" field."

Later I found out that the link cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-storage has been taken down.

Can anyone provide me a solution for de-identifying files from GCS? It would be really helpful.

Comment: I think the link is moved here: https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that ... we published it before it was ready to launch, but it's coming soon as an alternative to using dataflow.